# Makefile : How to runs 2 distinct shells?

Tags: node.js, bash, makefile, gnu-make, forever

I use a makefile to store my processes. One of these processes requires a server. Also, my `script.make` is such :

```make
end: server script
   # runs the 2 other tasks, 1st `server` then `script`
script:
   node ./node_script_with_server_queries.js   
server :
   node ./node_modules/.bin/forever ./node_modules/.bin/http-server
```

Then I runs the makefile, is start the server fine but then hang over forever :

```
$make -f ./script.make
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
Starting up http-server, serving ./ on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

I can make it work properly if I runs by hand the tasks in 2 different terminal.

**How to runs 2 distinct shells for each task  programmatically ?**

Comment: Why are you using make for this in the first place?!

Comment: It's a larger project, I simplified the code for question. I actually have 12 makefiles with ~30 commands each. Also, I'am new to such server side development and wonder how to proceed.

Comment: One slightly fiendish option in this case would be to use `make -j2`. Here you give _make_ permission to run the recipes for two targets at the same time. Just what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the server process into the background so that the client script can execute:

```
server :
   node ./node_modules/.bin/forever ./node_modules/.bin/http-server &
```